# TestNG test cases not auto compiling in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I have a Maven project imported as General --> existing workspace into my eclipse. 
When i write a new test file or edit an existing test file, the file does not seem to auto build. My build path is correct and the test out put folder is in \target\test-classes

any help here?

Comment: Is your  workspace autobuild enabled? (as in https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=342903#c11)

Comment: Do you have the maven eclipse plugin installed?

Comment: it worked after i gave the -vm arguments in the eclipse.ini file. Thanks guys

Comment: Could you add a little more detail?  I'm having the same issue, and I use vm args in my eclipse.ini.  Thanks.